# How to use array variable for show/collapese control?

Tags: vue.js

Trying to use array instead `show0` and `show1` variables,

```
<div id="demo2">
  <p>1. <button v-on:click="show[0] = !show[0]">Toggle</button>
    <div class="collapsible" v-show="!show[0]">Hello!</div>
  </p>
  <p>2. <button v-on:click="show[1] = !show[1]">Toggle</button>
    <div class="collapsible" v-show="!show[1]">Hello!</div>
  </p>
</div>
```

with `new Vue({  el:'#demo2', data:{show:[true,true]}  })`... **Not working**, and no error message.

---

NOTE.  When using simple

```
  <p>1. <button v-on:click="show0 = !show0">Toggle</button>
     <div class="collapsible" v-show="!show0">Hello!</div>
  </p> ...
```

and `new Vue({  el:'#demo1', data:{show0:true,show1:true}  })`
it is working fine.

PS: I see *complex* solutions like [this one](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MmzzvY?editors=1010) with template and component... but my aim here is only to understand how to use array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `show []` using `v-on:click="show[0] = !show[0]"`.

Vue cannot detect these kind of array manipulations. See [array change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

So use `vm.$set()` instead as follows

```
<p>1. <button v-on:click="$set(show, 0, !show[0])">Toggle</button>
  <div class="collapsible" v-show="!show[0]">Hello!</div>
</p>
```

Or else use array's `splice()` method:

```
<p>1. <button v-on:click="show.splice(0, 1, !show[0])">Toggle</button>
  <div class="collapsible" v-show="!show[0]">Hello!</div>
</p>
```

Comment: In terms of taste, I prefer `$set` notation ;-)  Good link for beginners, caveats and [common-gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/) as showed by @Stephan-v

Answer (score 1):

From Vue 1.0 but the same is applicable to Vue 2.0

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] =
> val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup
> these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method,
> or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method
> arr.$set(index, value) which is syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1,
> value).

https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

Here is the syntax you can use:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set

This should work:

```
v-on:click="$set(show, 0, !show[0])"
```

I would normally not do this kind of stuff inside of a inline handler though. The complexity will increase too much for a simple template. I would probably do this inside of a method like so:

```
this.$set(this.show, 0, !this.show[0])
```

Comment: Thanks @Stepan-v , make sense!   Can you show the solution in codebase?

Comment: Thanks!  good explanations  and important **common-gotchas link**. Sorry, clicked "accept" to the other solution that arrive first with a piece of code.